# Build fails for GreenDao 3.2 with CompilerOptions.versionToJdkLevel

Tags: android, greendao

After updating to Android Studio 2.3 trying to build the project causes a build failure.

> Execution failed for task ':app:greendao'.
>       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.impl.CompilerOptions.versionToJdkLevel(Ljava/lang/Object;)J

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to move

`classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.0'`

form `app/build.gradle` into top level `build.gradle` file.

Example:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.0'
    }
}
```